# External hard drive making noise; Can I eject drive during CHKDSK operation?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, bitlocker, chkdsk, decryption

Whenever I connect external HDD to my laptop. It shows decryption error and suggest to run `chkdsk /r`. So this time I did so as per this suggestion. It's taking a lot of time. What happens if I eject my hard disk while running `chkdsk /r`?
Also, my external hard drive is making some kind of unusual noise. What does this indicate?

Comment: Mechanical noise indicates a failure

Comment: Chkdsk /r takes a very long time to run.  A big drive can take many hours, up to a major fraction of a day, particularly if there is a lot of repair to do.  Once you start it, don't interrupt it or you will create additional corruption.  It would not be unusual to hear unfamiliar sounds because the process involves continuous, repetitive activity that can produce mechanical sounds; it may sound like "buzzing", for example.  I wouldn't worry about it unless it is extremely loud or if there is any kind of squealing or screeching sound.

Comment: thank you guys. infact hdd makes a kind of sound u feel like platters has been colliding. It may not be but it feels like.  does that mean i need to backup my elsewhere ?

Comment: If heads were colliding with the platters, you wouldn't feel it, and if you heard anything, it would be squealing.  There can be a "clunking" sound the actuators make, which might be what you're describing.  Hopefully the process is completed by now and the report should describe the drive's condition.  If you have any doubts or concerns, it is always prudent to backup the drive (even if you don't have doubts or concerns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not eject the drive during `chkdsk`:

- The dirty bit on your drive will only get cleared after you finish the scan.
- You won't be able to back up if it's not able to decrypt due to an unclean filesystem.
- Your files may actually be corrupted, and your drive may actually be failing.